# How to read from a text file in java when its not saved in the same place

Tags: java, io, filesystems

Im trying to write a function that will take a string, then open a file with that string name and read the text. I know how to do this, but im having trouble with the fact that my text files are not saved in the same place as my java file.

It looks like this.

```
Project name/src/program.java
Project name/resources/text.txt
```

Im using the File class, but dont know what to put in the File constructor to open to the right place.
ie. `File store = new File(xxxxxxxxxtext.txt)`
Help me out with what goes in front of the file name please. Also, this is java 6 and im on windows 8.

This is my code:

```
public static void areaSearch(String a) {
Scanner reader = null;
try {
reader = new Scanner(new File("../resources/" + a+ ".txt"));
}
catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("File: " + a +" not opended...");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative path if it's on an easy relative path from your project folder:

```
File file = File("../resources/text.txt");
```

Or use absolute path:

```
File file = File("C:\\abcfolder\\text.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks, but just like above i tried that and it is giving me a exception.

Comment: Do you have your java inside a package?

Comment: Yes, the default package.

Comment: That all seems like it should work, but for some reason i'm still getting a exception.

Comment: Im still not sure why the relative path does not work, but I got it to work using a absolute path for not. Thanks for the help and reformatting.

Answer (score 0):

Read [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). There are more, than 1 constructor for File class. Use:

```
public File(File parent, String child)
```

Comment: I have seen that online, and tried, but am not really sure how I would go about doing it. The child is the name of the file, but what goes into the constructor for the parent file then?

Comment: It is depending from which place your program is running. And it should not running from folder where you have sources, but probably from root of project, or from other place. One of ways of checking this is this (it is not the best one): File file = new File("something.txt"); System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()); Then you will know were you are. If it is root of project, then parent should be: File parent = new File("resources");